# checking regular expression for . and /

Tags: ruby, regex

I want regular expression for checking whether a word has `.` or `/` like `abcd.` or `abcd/a` or `abcd.def` or `abcd/def`. Any help will be gr8!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/[\/\.]/
```

Usage

```
if "some test. string" =~ /[\/\.]/
   # ..
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Both `/` and `.` are reserved characters in regex, so you would normally need to escape them. The exception to this is that `.` doesn't need to be escaped when it's in a character class, which is how you'd want to search in this case.

The escape chararacter in regex is `\`, so your `/` character becomes `\/`. Your `.` remains as it is.

Therfore, to check if a string contains either a `/` or a `.`, you would need a regex that looks something like this:

```
/[.\/]/
```

This will check any string and return true if it contains either of these characters anywhere within the string, regardless of what else is in the string.

Answer (score 1):

`/(\.|\/)/` matches the period or slash to a group.

`/[\/\.]/` just matches for period, slash or both.